# Анимированный border css

Tags: html, css

```css
.simple__button {
    margin-top: -9px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 47px;
    min-width: 107px;
    text-align: center;
}
.sb__ {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 7px 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px dashed #89cac0;
    height: 22px;
    min-width: 105px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="simple__button">
       <div class="sb__">Это текст!</div>
 </div>
```

Как реализовать анимированный "бегающий" border. Как сделать чтобы этот border двигался по кругу(прямоугольнику)?

Comment: смотри в сторону `svg`

Comment: http://www.sevensignature.com/blog/code/css-rotating-dashed-border/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Держи через `animation`

```css
@keyframes marching-ants {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0, 10px 100%, 0 10px, 100% 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 10px 0, 0 100%, 0 0, 100% 10px;
  }
}

.simple__button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 47px;
  min-width: 107px;
}

.sb__ {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 6px;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  height: 22px;
  min-width: 105px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #89cac0 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, #89cac0 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0, #89cac0 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0, #89cac0 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y;
  background-size: 10px 2px, 10px 2px, 2px 10px, 2px 10px;
  animation: marching-ants 400ms infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="simple__button">
  <div class="sb__">Это текст!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: То что надо! Просто и легко! Спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Полагаю вам нужен примерно такой эффект

```css
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.list-unstyled {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background: #defbfd;
}

nav {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "MuseoSansCyrl", sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}

nav .nav-ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2.9375rem 2.3125rem 0;
  text-align: center;
}

nav .nav-li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
}

nav .nav-li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.625rem 1.25rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav .nav-li a:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 99.5%;
  height: 2px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
}

nav .nav-li a:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 99.5%;
  height: 2px;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
}

nav .nav-li a:hover {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav .nav-li a:hover:before {
  transition: 0.1s transform linear, 0.1s height linear 0.1s;
  transform: translateX(0);
  height: 100%;
  border-color: #1fbfac;
}

nav .nav-li a:hover:after {
  transition: 0.1s transform linear 0.2s, 0.1s height linear 0.3s;
  transform: translateX(0);
  height: 100%;
  border-color: #1fbfac;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-ul">
    <li class="nav-li">
      <a href="#">Lorem</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-li">
      <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-li">
      <a href="#">Dolor</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-li">
      <a href="#">Ist</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Но совсем, должна быть постоянная анимация передвижения border`а. Именно dashed border

Comment: @kiLLro Не увидел слово "бегающий", прошу прощения

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно смотреть в сторону SVG и stroke анимации.
Как пособие я пользовался этим: https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/